# How to preserve line breaks when exporting MySQL data to a CSV file?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, export-to-csv

I need to export some data from mysql to a csv file. But one of the columns have line breaks and I need to export the data to a csv file saving break lines.

At this moment I am using the following sql query:

```
select username, description from users into outfile '/tmp/test.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But that sql query doesn't save break lines in the csv file. I am not an expert with MySQL, if someone could help me I'd be grateful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be hitting this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40320
The bug has been reported since 2008. I just tested and found it is still a bug in MySQL 8.0.3.

I can work around the bug this way:

```
SELECT username, REPLACE(description, '\n', '\\n') FROM users
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/test.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The file is exported with literal `\n` text (that is two characters). So when the data is loaded, the replacement must be reversed:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.csv' INTO TABLE users 
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '\\n', '\n');
```

This is not very graceful, of course, but it's a workaround.

The other option is to write an application to do the export and import, and refrain from using `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE` or `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: It worked fine! Thank you for your help! It seems incredible that we can find that bug 10 years later...

Comment: This is the best answer to this problem I've found so far (and I've looked far and wide). However, it did not quite work for me as described.  Using MySQL v5.7.12,  I found that I was not able to replace '\n' with '\\n' -- this still broke the CSV, as far as Excel was concerned. So, I replaced '\n' with '(newline)', and then handled the parsing of that text back to newlines downstream.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"` quote it

Example blow:

```py
with open("nl.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write('a,b\n1,"string\naaa"\n')
```

File looks like:

```bash
a,b
1,"string
aaa"
```

Pandas can handle it:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("nl.csv")
```

DataFrame:

```
    a   b
0   1   string\naaa
```

Ofcourse spark witl `multiLine=True`:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("nl.csv", header=True, multiLine=True)
```